# How to allow or add a hyphen(-) in an input element only at a certain position in Angular/HTML,JS with a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an input element for zip code. I want to allow only numbers in the input box and it should be of the form XXXXX or XXXXX-XXXX.

After entering the 5th digit, if the user enters 6th Digit, a hyphen should be placed automatically after 5th digit. And also allow the user to enter hyphen manually only at the 6th position(after 5th digit).

No other characters should be allowed. I am not getting how to achieve this.
Please suggest an efficient way to implement this in Angular typescript or Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool called [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask). Please feel free to answer if you got any coding solution.

After npm install, I used it in my input element as follows

```
<input mask="00000-0000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting familiar with how **directives** work in Angular. They are an essential part of the framework and very powerful once you know how they work and can build your own custom directives.

There are two types of **directives:** structural and attribute. In your situation, the most appropriate is the **attribute directive,** which allows you to change the appearance of a DOM element. Links to the docs bellow:

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should have to provide proper working code example, when you provide answer. In your answer you can go for comment section.

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment yet, for my reputation is not high enough. That won't stop me for trying to help though.

Comment: nobody will ever stop you. Just understand, Give Your answer with proper code example with it. It would be helpful to everyone in community. it would be helpful to you too. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by checking the last pressed key and eliminating it if it is not a number:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="this.inputValue" (keyup)="validate($event)">
```

```
public inputValue: string = '';

validate(params) {
  if (params.key >= 0 && params.key <= 9) {
    if (this.inputValue.length == 6) {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substr(0, 5) + '-' + params.key;
    }
  } else {
    this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substr(0, this.inputValue.length - 1);
  }
}
```